# How can I update a rich progress bar when the associated function is called from a thread?

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar, python-multithreading, rich

I intend to update my rich progress bar when the function that would have caused the progress is happen is called by spawning a thread.

The progress bar is initiated but does not progess.

```
import random
import time
from utils.log_util import Logger
import threading

from rich.progress import *

Logger.init('test')

randomlist = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    n = random.randint(1, 30)
    randomlist.append(n)


def print_list_items(randomlist, progress_bar, task):
    while (len(randomlist) > 0):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        item = randomlist[0]
        Logger.info(item)
        randomlist.remove(item)
        progress_bar.update(task, advance=1)


def start_print_list():
    with Progress(TextColumn("[progress.description]{task.description}"),
                  BarColumn(), TaskProgressColumn(),
                  TimeElapsedColumn()) as progress_bar:
        task_print_list = progress_bar.add_task(f"[green]Reading list 1.",
                                                total=len(randomlist))
        arguments = [randomlist, progress_bar, task_print_list]
        print_list_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_list_items,
                                             args=arguments)
        print_list_thread.start()


start_print_list()
```

As you will see in the screenshot, the progress bar is does not move past 0 percent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You launch a thread in `start_print_list` but immediately exit. Your thread will still be running, but because you have left the context manager Rich will stop the progress bar at 0%.

If you want to see the progress you could call `print_list_thread.join()` to wait for the thread to finish while displaying progress.

However, if you only have a single job you may as well call `print_list_items` directly. The `Progress` class will run its own thread to display updates while the rest of your code executes.